# Print a react functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

Hello everyone I have developed a react app using functional components and I need to print a particular page in the app. Since each page is a functional component, I thought maybe we could print a component separately. I tried using react-to-print but it supports only class components? Is this achievable through some NPM package?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `react-to-print` with functional component as it says in the FAQ's.
Here is the example that they use on the npm website

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';

import { ComponentToPrint } from './ComponentToPrint';

const Example = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactToPrint
        trigger={() => <button>Print this out!</button>}
        content={() => componentRef.current}
      />
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: My ComponentToPrint is also a functional component, will this solution work there too? Like can we set ref attribute in a functional component there?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just use the React Hook `forwardRef`.

To build on the previous answer, here's the two files in question:

**Example.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';

import { ComponentToPrint } from './ComponentToPrint';

const Example = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();

  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello world!');

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactToPrint
        trigger={() => <button>Print this out!</button>}
        content={() => componentRef.current}
      />
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} text={text} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

*Your React Function component to Print:*

**ComponentToPrint.js**

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const ComponentToPrint = forwardRef(( props, ref ) => {
  return (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
  </div>
)});

export default ComponentToPrint;
```